# Find number X, that if you increase it by 10% its sum of digits decrease by 11%

Tags: logic

I am stuck with this task:
Find the smalest positive number X, for which apply: If you increase this number by 10%, digit sum will decrease by 11%.

Mathematicaly I formulated this problem as:
find number X, for which is true
DS(X) = 0,89*DS(X*1,1)
and
X = abs(X)

I have tried brute force, without success.
Can anybody help me?
Any help will be welcome...

BR
KJ

Comment: Do you think the decrease should be exactly $11\%$, which indicates that the starting digit sum must be a multiple of $100$?  That requires at least $12$ digits in the number.  Or is $11\frac 19\%$ close enough, so the digit sum could decrease from $9$ to $8$?

Comment: @RossMillikan Given that / Conditional on i've seen this question before, it has to be exactly 11%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good construction / structure-finder-and-avoider problem, so I would encourage you to work this out yourself one step at a time. If you're stuck in any of these steps, explain what you've tried and what you're stuck on.

- The number is a multiple of 10. Let the number be $10X$.
- Since $DS(10X)$ decreases by 11%, hence $DS(10X)$ is a multiple of 100.
- $0.89 DS(10X) = DS(10X + X ) \equiv 2DS(X) \pmod{9}$.
- Hence $DS(10X)$ is a multiple of 3, and thus 300.

Assume that / In the event that $DS(10X) = 300$.

- Note that in $10X + X$, any carry over is either a 1 or a 0.
- In $10X + X$, each carry over of 1 reduces the digit sum by 9. A carry over of 0 doesn't change the digit sum.
- Hence, there are exactly $ \frac{ 600 - 300 \times 0.89 } { 9 }  = 37$ carry overs of 1.
- Since the units digit doesn't allow for a carry over (it is 0), so $10X$ has at least 38 digits.

Assume that / In the event that $10X$ has exactly 38 digits

- In order to get a carry over, remember that we're adding at most 1 each time, so the sum of each pair of neighboring digits is at least 9.
- For the leading digit to have a carry over, it must have a digit of $\underline{ \quad } $ (fill in the blank).
- Recall that we don't need the units digit to have a carry over, and that the units digit is actually 0.
- Now, greedily assign digits to get the smallest possible 38 digit number, subject to all of the above constraints:

> $90909093999999999999999999999999999990$.

Verify that this number works (which it should because of the above arguments).

Note: If we couldn't find such a 38 digit number, then we could try for a 39+ digit number (or subsequently $DS(10X) = 600$), while relaxing some of the above constraints.

Comment: Dear Calvin,

many thanks!
Your solution is correct.